# Java how to pass the timeformat in java "Fri Jan 24 12:22:13 +0000 2014"

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have got the  following created date   "Fri Jan 24 12:22:13 +0000 2014" from twitter , but when it comes to parsing , the goes to unparsable exception error at "z"

Would you please tell em what is the correct time format  ? 
The below is my code

```
String dateString = fullS.substring(0, 11) + " "+ year; 
            String timeZoneHK = content.getTimeZone();

            SimpleDateFormat inputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat outputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss EEE MMM dd yyyy");
            Date date;
            try {
                TimeZone timezone = null;
                date = inputDf.parse(dateString);
                if(timeZoneHK.equals("Hong Kong")){
                    timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Hong_Kong");                  
                }
                outputDf.setTimeZone(timezone);
                String result  =outputDf.format(date);
                //System.out.println(outputDf.format(date));
                viewHolder.txtDate.setText(result);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Exception

```
01-24 22:10:30.061: W/System.err(12573): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Jan 24 13:37:08 +0000 2014" (at offset 0)
```

Comment: what's the content of dateString ?

Comment: I don't see a z in your date string. Also, please post the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Joda-Time

This kind of work is much easier with the third-party open-source date-time library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

```java
String input = "Fri Jan 24 12:22:13 +0000 2014";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" );

// Parse as UTC/GMT (no time zone offset) so we may conveniently compare to input.
DateTime dateTimeUtc = formatter.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ).parseDateTime( input );

// Convert to Hong Kong time zone. 
DateTime dateTimeHongKong = dateTimeUtc.toDateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Hong_Kong" ) );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeHongKong: " + dateTimeHongKong );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeUtc: 2014-01-24T12:22:13.000Z
dateTimeHongKong: 2014-01-24T20:22:13.000+08:00
```

## Back To Date

If you need a java.util.Date for other purposes, convert your DateTime.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use complete date String `"Fri Jan 24 12:22:13 +0000 2014"` if wanted to apply the specified `format`. And change `z` to `Z`:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

Refer to:  [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> Z - time zone (RFC 822) - (Time Zone) Z/ZZ/ZZZ:-0800 - ZZZZ:GMT-08:00 ZZZZZ:-08:00